# How to propagate errors out of IPython profile to a notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

When an error happens inside the start-up code of an [IPython profile](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/intro.html#profiles), `ipython` displays this error immediately.

For example, `raise Exception('something bad')` in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/01_error.py` yields

```
----> 1 raise Exception('something bad')
Exception: something bad
```

right on the first line.

However, when using `ipython notebook`, the same error seems **silently ignored**.
It doesn't appear in the browser nor in the console window which launched it.

Is there a way to abort the notebook app when an error happens or at least display the error?